# Did Agnetha and Anni-Frid always sing in unison?

Tags: harmony, voice, songwriting, pop-music

I was listening to some ABBA songs that I hadn't paid much attention to since my childhood, and it occurred to me that, even though they are known for being a multi-singer group, they never really sing traditional harmonies. Particularly, whenever Agnetha and Frida sing the same lyrics with the same rhythm, they seem to be singing in unison. This in contrast to many of their contemporaries, such as the Bee Gees.

Is singing in unison indeed the secret sauce of ABBA's vocal style, or am I hearing this incorrectly?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131742/discussion-on-question-by-shiny-and-new-did-agnetha-and-anni-frid-always-sing-in).

Answer (score 4):

You are hearing this incorrectly. You should listen more closely, and possibly to a wider range of their songs. ABBA songs have about the same mixture of solo voices, unison lines and multi-part harmony as other pop songs from multi-singer groups. In comparison with the Bee Gees, since you named them as a contrast, the mix of different textures is very similar.

Comment: Probably way more multi-part harmony!

Comment: @Tim OP contrasted ABBA with the BeeGees. I'd say the mixture is similar in both cases.

Comment: I completely agree with the answer, +1. It is worth pointing out that they did have a kind of trademark two female unison vocal in certain sections of many of their songs.